# Observable not returning value as printed out

Tags: java, observable, couchbase

I've been trying to get an Observable to return back a `Map<String,JSONObject>`, but it fails to do so. The print statements show the correct return value, but not sure why this is returning an incomplete value.

```java
  @Override
  @Retryable(value = {CouchbaseException.class})
  public Mono<Map<String, JsonObject>> query(String query, List<String> params) {
    N1qlParams n1qlParams = N1qlParams.build()
        .adhoc(true);
    Map<String, JsonObject> resultMap = new HashMap();
    N1qlQuery n1qlQuery = N1qlQuery.parameterized(query, JsonArray.from(params), n1qlParams);
    Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryResult> queryResult = bucket.async().query(n1qlQuery)
        .timeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .retryWhen(anyOf(BackpressureException.class).max(3)
            .delay(Delay.exponential(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 32, 2)).build())
        .retryWhen(anyOf(TemporaryFailureException.class)
            .max(2)
            .delay(Delay.fixed(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)).build())
        .onErrorResumeNext(exp -> {
          return Observable.error(exp);
        });
    Observable<Map<String, JsonObject>> metricsMap = queryResult.flatMap(qr ->
        qr.info()).map(n1qlMetrics -> {
      resultMap.put("metrics", n1qlMetrics.asJsonObject());
      log.info("METRICS: " + resultMap.toString());
      return resultMap;
    });
    Observable<Map<String, JsonObject>> resultObsMap = queryResult.flatMap(asyncN1qlQueryResult ->
        asyncN1qlQueryResult.errors().flatMap(error -> {
          return Observable
              .error(new Exception("unable to execute n1ql query " + error.toString()));
        })
            .switchIfEmpty(asyncN1qlQueryResult.rows())
    ).map(row -> {
      JsonObject json = ((AsyncN1qlQueryRow) row).value();
      return json;
    }).map(results -> {
      resultMap.put("results", results);
      log.info("RESULTS: " + resultMap.toString());
      return resultMap;
    });
//    log.info("resultObsMap: " + resultObsMap..toString());
//
    Observable<Map<String, JsonObject>> retObservable = Observable
        .zip(resultObsMap, metricsMap, (r, m) -> {
          r.putAll(m);
          return r;
        });
    //retObservable.subscribe(System.out::println);
    return Mono.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(retObservable));
  }
```

The 2 print statements print the below CORRECT values:

> 2020-07-30 09:41:19.402 INFO  [cb-computations-4] com.aexp.eimp.dbtestsuite.couchbase.service.impl.CouchbaseAsyncServiceImpl - METRICS: {metrics={"executionTime":"780.964µs","resultCount":2,"resultSize":2858,"elapsedTime":"841.098µs"}}
> 2020-07-30 09:41:19.406 INFO  [cb-computations-3]

> com.aexp.eimp.dbtestsuite.couchbase.service.impl.CouchbaseAsyncServiceImpl - RESULTS: {metrics={"executionTime":"780.964µs","resultCount":2,"resultSize":2858,"elapsedTime":"841.098µs"}, results={"bucket_admin":{"name":"${__RandomString(20,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}","notificationEnrollment":{"insertTS":1503530927070,"id":"0000255BAIHSDCY","type":"ENCRYPTEDACCOUNT","issuer":"001","domain":"","apps":{"app":{"enrollmentInfoList":[{"features":[{"featureUserIdentifier":{"id":"BAIHSDCY0000255","type":"ENCRYPTEDACCOUNT","issuer":"001","domain":"CARD"},"featureInfoList":[{"featureName":"PAYMENT_RECEIVED_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"PAYMENT_REMINDER_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"STMT_NOTIFICATION_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"OFFERS","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"GOLDEN_GOOSE_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true}]}],"appVersion":"1.0","insertTS":1503530927066,"type":"Push","value":true,"deviceInfo":{"deviceType":"deviceType","deviceModel":"deviceModel","osVersion":"OSVersion","deviceId":"17BBE19B241C219C3FE766FAE1887CE2","deviceOS":"deviceOS","deviceToken":"0838273194687468409056870471453029636922734387856368468017913851"},"status":"ACTIVE"}],"applicationGroup":"INTERNAL__10","id":"com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.carbon.notifications.messages"}}},"id":"100173"}}}

But the return value is incorrect and does not make sense - you can see here that the values in the JSON fields are missing, and the whole response seems to be incomplete.

```
{"metrics":{"cryptoManager":null,"empty":false,"names":["executionTime","resultCount","resultSize","elapsedTime"]},"results":{"cryptoManager":null,"empty":false,"names":["bucket_admin"]}}
```

We're expecting

```
{metrics:{"executionTime":"780.964µs","resultCount":2,"resultSize":2858,"elapsedTime":"841.098µs"}, results:{"bucket_admin":{"name":"${__RandomString(20,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}","notificationEnrollment":{"insertTS":1503530927070,"id":"0000255BAIHSDCY","type":"ENCRYPTEDACCOUNT","issuer":"001","domain":"","apps":{"app":{"enrollmentInfoList":[{"features":[{"featureUserIdentifier":{"id":"BAIHSDCY0000255","type":"ENCRYPTEDACCOUNT","issuer":"001","domain":"CARD"},"featureInfoList":[{"featureName":"PAYMENT_RECEIVED_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"PAYMENT_REMINDER_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"STMT_NOTIFICATION_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"OFFERS","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true},{"featureName":"GOLDEN_GOOSE_ALERT","attributes":[{"value":"8","key":"daysBeforeDue"}],"featurePreferenceValue":true}]}],"appVersion":"1.0","insertTS":1503530927066,"type":"Push","value":true,"deviceInfo":{"deviceType":"deviceType","deviceModel":"deviceModel","osVersion":"OSVersion","deviceId":"17BBE19B241C219C3FE766FAE1887CE2","deviceOS":"deviceOS","deviceToken":"0838273194687468409056870471453029636922734387856368468017913851"},"status":"ACTIVE"}],"applicationGroup":"INTERNAL__10","id":"com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.carbon.notifications.messages"}}},"id":"100173"}}}
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrect here?